# Background Chrome Browsing Session issue

Tags: java, php, mysql, google-chrome

hey Ive run into a pretty major problem in my application. I have a java application that connects to `http://aeroscripts.x10.bz/dashboard.php?Data1=x&Data2=y&Data3=z` via a URLConnection and it sends data which is recieved and processed by php and Mysql

The problem is I am looking at the exact same page on my website and yet I see none of the data that is being sent by the java application. I figured well this is because it is connecting to it in the background Im not actually going to see what its sending when im looking at the page in chrome

is there any way i can share information from this "background browsing session" and the current browsing session that im looking at on my screen? Either via php or java or is there a better solution all together any help would be much appreciated if you have any question or want me to explain more feel free to ask hopefully i wasnt to vague

Comment: You want to capture and view the HTTP traffic?  Try a sniffer like Wireshark.

Comment: no i want to share browsing data between a background browsing session and the current session that im viewing on my computer

Comment: What do you mean by "*browsing data*" ?

Comment: the data that im sending to the server via my java application its just integers and strings

Answer (score 0):

the answer was rather complex because i couldnt transfer the data i needed from the background browsing session to my current browsing session i had to use the `users` username stored in a session as a unique identifier between my java application and my Php/MySQL server because it was stored in both the background browsing session and the current browsing session thus it was a common piece of data linked to both the java app and my server I simply used the common data to read and write from the database pulling and pushing the other information that i required.